# Bind <select> list to css class

Tags: jquery

I have a `<select>` list and an arrow css class as follows:

```
<ul id="city-list">
    <li>
        <form action="#">
            <select id="listcc" name="escities">
                <option>Aspen</option>
                <option>Tokyo</option>
                <option>Cannes</option>
                <option>Capetown</option>
                <option>Courchevel</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`class="arrow-down"` is just small arrow constructed with css.

CSS code:

```
.arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #c2a54d;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

I would like the user when pressing on the arrow to open the `<select>` list. Any ideas on how to bind these together?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't open select elements programatically, so the simple is answer is that this can't be done. There are of course hacks, like increasing the height, turning it into a multiple etc. but they are all hacks, and the best looking solution is to use a custom select based on a list or something similar.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question directly, but consider a solution like [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) that gives you a bunch of nice features wrapped around select elements.

Comment: i am actually using this plugin if it makes things easier... http://exodecreations.com/jQuery/jqDropDown.html#plugin_options i wouldn't mind a simple CSS hack either.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multiple select element (hidden by default) and toggle the visibility by clicking the arrow?

http://jsfiddle.net/FLQe8/2/

jQuery

```
$("body").on("click", ".arrow-down", function(){
    $("#listcc").toggle();
})
```

HTML

```
<ul id="city-list">
    <li>
        <form action="#">
            <select style="display:none" multiple id="listcc" name="escities">
                <option>Aspen</option>
                <option>Tokyo</option>
                <option>Cannes</option>
                <option>Capetown</option>
                <option>Courchevel</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i am actually using this plugin for the `select list` if it makes things easier... exodecreations.com/jQuery/jqDropDown.html#plugin_options

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/acQZ7/

**JS:-**

```
var state = false;
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".arrow-down").on("click", function () {
        state = !state;
        $("#listcc").prop("size", state ? $("option").length : 1);
    });
});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<ul id="city-list">
    <li>
        <form action="#">
            <select id="listcc" name="escities">
                <option>Aspen</option>
                <option>Tokyo</option>
                <option>Cannes</option>
                <option>Capetown</option>
                <option>Courchevel</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Edited**

```
$(function () {
    $("#ddComOS").jqDropDown({
        toggleBtnName: "arrow-down"
    });
});
```

Comment: i am using this script for the select list - http://exodecreations.com/jQuery/jqDropDown.html#plugin_options

Comment: @JovanniJiorgio If you are using any plugin, you don't have to bind these events, the plugin takes care of this. It basically hides your select control and render its own ul li structure with custom `CSS` and `events.`

Comment: yes it does but then how do i link this to my `class="arrow-down"` ?